# Is it okay to sing Zemirot for Shabbas day on Shabbas night?

Tags: shabbat-songs

I know there are zemirot that are generally for Shabbas night, and others that are for Shabbas day, but is it okay to sing them whenever on shabbas?

Is there any significance to why they are traditionally sung on Friday night or Shabbas day?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11174

Answer (score 1):

By many chassidic groups a large variety of zemiros from throughout the bencher are sung by shalosh seudos. In my community for example we sing Yom Zeh LYisroel then even though it is generally a first meal zemer, and a bulk of the songs sung are from the day seudah. With the exception of the zemiros from the Arizal it doesn't seem like they are specific to any of the seudos, especially Kah Ribon and Tzur Mishelo which do not even refer to Shabbos.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many _chasidim_ sing part of "_Baruch Hashem yom yom_" at the second meal and finish it at the third.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard from a Yekke that they divide the Zemiros between day and night depending on the season - on the longer winter nights, they sing the majority at night, and in the summer they save more for the day.