# Timing of Shabbat Zemirot

Tags: shabbat, shabbat-songs

In viewing the Shabbat *zemirot*, I noticed that some were listed for the evening, some for the afternoon, and some for the 3rd meal.

Is there any pattern or characteristic that qualifies a specifc zemer to be sung at one of these meals?

The chazzan in my shul said that in general, night time zemirot should not be sung during the day and vice versa. The only two exceptions he mentioned were *Tzur Mishelo* and *Kah Ribon* that were appropriate for any of the 3 meals. I haven't been able to ask him why this is. Is there any halacha or strong minhag that would prohibit a zemer from being sung at the inappropriate meal?

Comment: Between these there should be a dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11174/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53879/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes siree, works for me! You can close this question as dupe.